# Return the array from a struct c language

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, function-definition

I'm trying to return the array inside the struct.

I have to make a new array inside the struct integer_array and then return the array at the end.

The assignment is to take a string array and count each index and how what is the size of it.

So an array that is

```
["This", "is", "the", "way"]
```

should return :

```
[4, 2, 3, 3]
```

The code I came up with is this, but it returns an empty array

> ```
> #ifndef STRUCT_STRING_ARRAY
> #define STRUCT_STRING_ARRAY
> typedef struct s_string_array
> {
>     int size;
>     char** array;
> } string_array;
> #endif
>
> #ifndef STRUCT_INTEGER_ARRAY
> #define STRUCT_INTEGER_ARRAY
> typedef struct s_integer_array
> {
>     int size;
>     int* array;
> } integer_array;
> #endif
>
> integer_array* my_count_on_it(string_array* str){
>     integer_array* intArr;
>     int size = str->size,  count =0;
>     intArr= malloc(1);  
>     intArr[0].array = malloc(size*sizeof(intArr));  
>     for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
>         for(int j =0 ; str->array[i][j] != '\0';j++) count++;
>         intArr->array[i] = count;
>         count =0;
>     }
>     return intArr;
> }
> ```

**NOTE I can't change the structures, and I have only to implement this function above**

Comment: `intArr[0].array = malloc(size*sizeof(intArr));` Shouldn't that be `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Read the manual for `malloc`. In particular, with Paul's comment and your `malloc(1)` call in mind.

Comment: How do you test for the array being empty? Is it maybe connected to the fact that you didn't set `intArr->size`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips i found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The argument of the call of malloc

```
intArr= malloc(1);
```

is incorrect. There is allocated only one byte instead of `sizeof( integer_array )` bytes.

Again in this statement

```
intArr[0].array = malloc(size*sizeof(intArr));
```

the argument of the call of malloc is incorrect. You need to write

```
intArr[0].array = malloc( size * sizeof( int ) );
```

Also you forgot to set the data member `size` of the object `intArr`.

Instead of this manually written loop

```
for(int j =0 ; str->array[i][j] != '\0';j++) count++
```

you could use the standard C function `strlen`.

For starters the structures should be declared like

```
typedef struct s_string_array
{
    size size;
    char **array;
} string_array;
```

and

```
typedef struct s_integer_array
{
    size_t size;
    size_t *array;
} integer_array;
```

Within the function you should check whether a memory was allocated successfully.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_string_array
{
    size_t size;
    char **array;
} string_array;

typedef struct s_integer_array
{
    size_t size;
    size_t *array;
} integer_array;

integer_array * my_count_on_it( const string_array *str )
{
    integer_array *intArr = malloc( sizeof( *intArr ) );
    int success = intArr != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        intArr->array = malloc( str->size * sizeof( *intArr->array ) );
        success = intArr->array != NULL;
        
        if ( success )
        {
            intArr->size = str->size;
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < str->size; i++ )
            {
                intArr->array[i] = strlen( str->array[i] );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            free( intArr );
            intArr = NULL;
        }
    }
    
    return intArr;
}    

int main(void) 
{
    char * s[] = { "This", "is", "the", "way" };
    string_array str = { sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ), s };
    
    integer_array *intArr = my_count_on_it( &str );
    
    if ( intArr != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < intArr->size; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%zu ", intArr->array[i] );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        free( intArr->array );
        free( intArr );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the array size in the struct.

So the new function would be

> ```
> integer_array* my_count_on_it(string_array* str){
> integer_array* intArr;
> int size = str->size,  count =0;
> intArr= malloc(1);  
> intArr->size = size;
> intArr->array = malloc(intArr->size*sizeof(intArr->size));  
> for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
>     for(int j =0 ; str->array[i][j] != '\0';j++) count++;
>     intArr->array[i] = count;
>     count =0;
> }
> return intArr; }
> ```

Comment: The `malloc(1)` (asking for 1 byte) allocation is still wrong. And the other one as well. It may not immediately crash on you, but it has the potential to.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about which one?

Comment: `malloc(1)` is wrong, because the struct isn't 1 byte long, so use `malloc (sizeof(integer_array))` instead, the other one `malloc(intArr->size*sizeof(intArr->size))` is correct by coincidence, but it should rather be `malloc(intArr->size*sizeof(int))` because it's an array of ints, not sizes (yours would break if someone changes the type of size...)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips, it seems to work fine after the modification to what you have suggested.
I'm learning a lot about malloc today :)